# How can I express react-three/drei pivot control rotation as Euler angles with respect to the pivot control coordinate system?

Tags: three.js, react-three-drei

I have a React, ThreeJS project. I am using [drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei) Pivot Controls to allow the user to move an object. `rotation={getPivotControlsRotation()}` sets the initial rotation of the Pivot Controls to be aligned with the box geometry. And everything works great. But the matrices that I get from `onDrag` are not with respect to the pivot controls. Because of this, if I rotate about the X axis of the Pivot Controls, and extract the rotations as shown below, rotation has values in X, Y, and Z. I need it to be expressed with respect to the Pivot Controls where Y and Z are 0. How can I do this?

```
const rotationMatrix = new Matrix4()
    .extractRotation(userTransformationRef.current.local)

const rotation = new Euler().setFromRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix); 


<PivotControls
    depthTest={false}
    autoTransform={true}
    anchor={[0, 0, 0]}
    rotation={getPivotControlsRotation()}
    onDrag={(l, dL, w, dW) => {
        userTransformationRef.current = {
            local: l.clone(),
            dLocal: dL.clone(),
            world: w.clone(),
            dWorld: dW.clone(),
        };
    }}
    onDragEnd={() => setUserTransformation()}
>
    <mesh
        matrix={matrix}
        matrixAutoUpdate={false}
    >
        <boxGeometry
            args={[
                width,
                height,
                depth,
            ]}
        ></boxGeometry>
        <meshStandardMaterial
            color={color}
        />
    </mesh>
</PivotControls>
```

[image: Pivot controls]